# Uninstalling app from specific device only

Tags: applications, uninstallation

Is there a way to remove an app from only one device when using the same account over two devices?

I've just got a tablet - which is currently syncing settings and downloading all the apps that I have obtained from the market on my phone.  I won't need all these apps and would like to remove some from just the tablet (but leave them available for restore on the phone etc).

Is this possible?  Does the phone have an independent "installed app" list to the tablet?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they have separate lists - you can uninstall from the tablet or phone without affecting the other device.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use your web browser from your computer and go to the [My Apps section](https://play.google.com/apps) of *Google Play*. Here you can select the device you want to remove the app from, and click the trashcan icon next to it. This will uninstall the app from that device only.

[image: Uninstall]
<sup>Trashcan icon to uninstall an app from the selected device</sup>